# How to access specific item from list and replace it using Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an issue in accessing the list items and replacing specific item from it. Below is the resulting list after splitting string by new line('\n').

```
def lst = [Node: , Message group: , Application: appl, Severity: critical];
```

My question here is to how to access specific item from the list and replace that with empty value using Groovy script.

I mean for example , access 'Application' from the list and set its value to empty('') using Groovy script.

Comment: This is a list or a map?

Comment: That is no list, but a map -- and the code there is broken too.  Half of the keys have no value and "Message group" lacks some quotes.  Or it _is_ a list, but then everything lacks the quotes.

Comment: Bawge, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a list you can build a new just iterate the list find required item and replace it.

```
def data='''
Node:
Message group:
Application: appl
Severity: critical
'''

def lst = new StringReader(data).readLines()

for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
    if(lst[i].startsWith('Application:'))lst[i]='Application:'
}

println lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you saw the comments, the data you defined is a map, not a list.

You can simply update value as shown below

```
def map = [Node: '', 'Message group': '', Application: 'appl', Severity: 'critical']
println map
//Update value
map.Application = ''
//or you can use any of below notation as well to update
//map['Application'] = ''
//map.put('Application', '') 
println map
```

You can try online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/Yz9JM1)</kbd>